# Call methods from another class with namespace (PHP)

Tags: php, class, oop, namespaces

I have a problem with classes. I am using https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ for autoload classes.

------------------------------------ /home/classes/a/casea.php

```
namespace Classes\A\CaseA;

class ClassA {

  public function MethodA()

  {

    $resultA = 'Method A works!';
    return $resultA;

  }

}
```

------------------------------------ /home/classes/b/caseb.php

```
namespace Classes\B\CaseB;

class ClassB {

  public function MethodB()

  {

    // Classes\A\CaseA\ClassA  MethodA() don't work here.
    // I tried this, but didn't work.
    $obj = new Classes\A\CaseA\ClassA;
    $result = $obj->MehodA();

    return $result;

  }

}

$classb = new Classes\B\CaseB\ClassB;
$show = $classb->MethodB();
echo $show;
```

------------------------------------ Autoload

```
## PHP-FIG Autoload
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

    // project-specific namespace prefix
    $prefix = 'Classes\\';

    // base directory for the namespace prefix
    $base_dir = PATH . '/classes/';

    // does the class use the namespace prefix?
    $len = strlen($prefix);
    if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
        // no, move to the next registered autoloader
        return;
    }

    // get the relative class name
    $relative_class = substr($class, $len);

    // replace the namespace prefix with the base directory, replace namespace
    // separators with directory separators in the relative class name, append
    // with .php
    $file = $base_dir . strtolower(str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class)) . '.php';

    // if the file exists, require it
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
    }

});
```

Error is the following text.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Classes\B\Classes\A\ClassA' not found in /home/domain.tld/classes/b/classb.php:11 Stack trace: #0
```

Comment: And where's your autoload? I see only 2 classes.

Comment: I added, thanks a lot.

Comment: To format code as code, add a blank line and indent the first line of code four spaces. ;-)

Comment: So, what exactly happens when you try to make the new ClassA and it doesn't work? Is there an error?

Comment: Also, autoload registration is missed. How do you connect files? Do you have extra file e.g. `index.php` and call your autoload from it and only then classes A and B?

Comment: Thanks for your comments and helps.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but MethodB returns the result of MethodA, but MethodA doesn't return anything, other than an implicit null return.

Comment: Hmm, are your files really called casea.php and caseb.php, or is that a typo in the question here? The file name needs to match the class name.

Comment: Please can you check again? I added some print codes now.

Comment: I think, problems come from calling the another class. The codes looks /classes/b path, but it should be /classes path. Did I explain the problem?

Comment: namespaces and folder/file names are same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solve the problem, if anybody need like that, can use following codes.

in caseb.php

```
namespace Classes\B\CaseB;

use Classes\A\CaseA\ClassA;

class ClassB extends ClassA {

  public function MethodB()

  {

    $result = parent::MehodA();

    return $result;

  }

}
```